# Python generator yields same value each call

Tags: python, generator

I want this generator to yield the cosine of each successive value from a list, but am getting the same value each time.

```
import math     
angles = range(0,361,3)

# calculate x coords:    
def calc_x(angle_list):
    for a in angle_list:
        yield round(radius * cos(radians(a)), 3)
```

Yields the same value with each call: Why is this and how do I fix it?

```
>>>calc_x(angles).next()
5.0
>>>calc_x(angles).next()
5.0
>>>calc_x(angles).next()
5.0
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Every time you call `calc_x` you create a *new* generator.  What you need to do is create one and then keep using it:

```
calc = calc_x(angles)
next(calc)
next(calc)
# etc.
```

Comment: excellent, thank you. I got tripped up looking at examples using while loops.