# Why does this itertools function work outside another function but not inside?

Tags: python, function, python-itertools

I am trying to find all possible combinations using itertools product in Python. The code works but as soon as I try to yield my results instead of print them it only goes through one cycle or repetition, ignoring the repeat argument.

This works:

```
for i in range(1, 4):
    g = itertools.product(range(5), repeat=i)
    for j in range(len(al) ** i):
        print(next(g))
```

This doesn't:

```
def func():
    for i in range(1, 4):
        g = itertools.product(range(5), repeat=i)
        for j in range(len(al) ** i):
            yield next(g)

for i in range(100):
    print(next(func()))
```

I have tried playing with the next statements and putting the itertools function in various places. Google isn't very helpful as all results are just very basic itertools tutorials.

How can I make it work in a function?

Comment: What is the error message? What is the expected result?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python generator yields same value each call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15216972/python-generator-yields-same-value-each-call)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want this?

```
f = func()
for i in range(100):
    print(next(f))
```

For next time please provide an mre: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a new generator each time the body of the loop is called. This means you're always starting from the first value. You want to create the generator once and then iterate over all of the values produced.

Instead of using the `range` class, just iterate directly:

```py
for value in func():
    print(value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks people! Two good answers have already been provided:

```
f = func()
for i in range(100):
    print(next(f))

for value in func():
    print(value)
```